# How to implement a hook for componentDidMount with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm try to implement useEffect for my componentDidMount, but I don't know how do this for this case:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    logNavego(this.props.history.location.pathname + 
    this.props.history.location.search )
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen(location => {
      logNavego(location.pathname + location.search)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only wish to call `history.listen` on initial render and clean up the listener on unmount, you can call `useEffect` with `empty array` as a dependency array and return the cleanup function

```
useEffect(() => {
    logNavego(props.history.location.pathname + props.history.location.search )
    const unlisten = props.history.listen(location => {
      logNavego(location.pathname + location.search)
    });
    return () => {
       unlisten();
    }
  }, [])
```

You can refer to the **[`useEffect` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)** for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  // all your code that you put in  componentDidMount method
}, [])
```

> in useEffect we're using []. that [] is similar to componentDidMount.

Now if you want to use componentDidUpdate then you need to pass state in [].

for Ex. if count is update at that time you want to change anything then see this code.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // all your code goes here related to count state.
}, [count])
```

so above code will trigger re-render if count changes otherwise it'll not call.